# Background worker has the wrong return type

Tags: c#, async-await, task, backgroundworker

Having the following code:

```
private async Task backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync (
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
        );
    }

    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
    });

    PlaylistsResource.ListRequest request = youtubeService.Playlists.List("snippet");
    request.Mine = true;
    PlayListResponse = request.Execute();

}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
```

When I build the solution I get:

```
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task YouTubeDesktopPlayer.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)' has the wrong return type
```

How can I change the return type? I'm little bit confused, I don't understand how is working the `async Task` with a `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: You'd need it to be `async void` in order to be compatible with DoWorkEventHandler.

Comment: That's it. It's working.

Comment: There's little point in using BackgroundWorker if you already use asynchronous methods. You could simply use the `async void` syntax in the event (eg button click) that starts the download. In fact, with `async/await` and the TPL there's little point in using BackgroundWorker in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** use an `async void DoWork` event handler. It will fire `RunWorkerCompleted` before `DoWork` is completed and it won't capture exceptions properly.

If you need to do asynchronous work on a background thread (which is rare), then use `Task.Run` instead. I have a [blog series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html) that goes into details, but the gist would be:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  // DoWork code goes here
  UserCredential credential;
  ...
  PlayListResponse = request.Execute();
});

// RunWorkerCompleted code goes here
MessageBox.Show("OK");
```